# How can I revive someone without being next to them in Neverwinter?

Tags: neverwinter

I'm currently working on a healer build (Devout Cleric) for Neverwinter after playing for a while as a DPS. While so far I've been mostly able to keep my party members alive during combat, there are times where someone will drop unconscious (especially if I'm out of Divinity). When that happens, my main problem is that I need to get next to them to revive them before they die.

Is there any way I can revive someone without being right next to them? I feel like I've been revived that way playing as a DPS before, but I'm not positive. I'm looking for an Artifact, Enchantment, gear piece, or something else that will let me revive someone from a distance. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

The only way what you describe could happen is if another player used a [Scoll of Mass Life.](https://neverwinter.fandom.com/wiki/Scroll_of_Mass_Life)

This item is the only way you could revive another player without being right next to them. The only catch is, you have to be unconscious yourself to use it!